# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED on peerConnection.addStream in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I fetch a `LocalMediaStream` using `window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia` and supply this to my peer connection by calling `peerConnection.addStream(stream)`, then I immediately get this:

```
Exception {
    message: "",
    result: 2147549183,
    name: "NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED",
    filename: "<my-url>",
    lineNumber: 289,
    columnNumber: 0,
    inner: null,
    data: null
}
```

NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED is a very broad error that arises when a configuration or a constraint is not met for some internal API to be called.

Does anyone know why this is happening? The result is that I cannot share my local stream to the remote peer.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you'd done before calling addStream?  In particular, was this before or after createOffer/etc?  What version of Firefox?  (renegotiation (anything that would trigger onnegotiationneeded) is only supported in Fx 38 (current Beta) and later, for example).

Comment: Solved. The issue was adding the stream twice. Firefox doesn't like that. Chrome tolerates it. The issue was reported with a sensible error message ("already added") when I updated from Firefox 32 to 38.

Comment: 32 is ... old.  The only thing that old supported is 31ESR, and that's about to go away for 38ESR (ESR releases are every 7 regular releases, and get security fixes (only)).

Comment: True, but it should still work!